# How Can I connect My Solar Power System?

Tags: dc, solar-cell, inverter, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I  brought this [50A Solar Controller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32818868189.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.5c717d77XMLKFr&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_6_10065_10068_319_317_10548_10696_453_10084_454_10083_10618_10307_10135_10821_537_10302_536_10133_10059_10884_10887_321_322_10103%2Csearchweb201603_55%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=f479b470-b5fe-43bc-a831-7bb05f360a7c-0&algo_pvid=f479b470-b5fe-43bc-a831-7bb05f360a7c&transAbTest=ae803_3) now I want to connect an inverter to it and they said to connect the inverter directly to the battery. I also brought a 100W Solar Panel and MC4 Wires, etc

What is these "60A/50A/40A/30A/20A/10A "? I choose the 50A one and wanted to know the Amps are used for DC Load or what's the use of selecting "60A/50A/40A/30A/20A/10A" if it is to be connected to the battery eventually?

The reason for not wanting to connect it to the battery is: The Protections (Load, Over Charging, Deep Charging, etc) go away if I connect the inverter to the battery directly.

Answer (score 1):

The solar controller you bought goes between the solar panels and the battery bank. It is designed to control the charging of the battery bank only, not to control the inverter / battery connection.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha! So the DC Out Load is useless? (I'm asking cause I have no idea what 50A are for)

Answer (score 1):

There's a diagram on the page you link showing that the inverter should be connected to the battery direct. These controllers have a DC out that is intended to allow it to disconnect the loads at a particular terminal voltage, so that the battery doesn't over-discharge, but in this case the capacity of that output is limited (it's probably done with a MOSFET), and the inverter can potentially take more than that - unless it's a only a small one.

Given that limitation, you need to check that the inverter has its own undervoltage trip if it's going to be left unattended, or you risk pulling the battery state of charge low enough that it'd be permanently damaged.

[image]

Comment: "you risk pulling the battery state of charge low enough that it'd be permanently damaged." Yup thats what I'm worried about!

Comment: What load is the inverter supplying, and what is its rating? The webpage indicates 360W max for the DC out, so if it's less than that you may get away with connecting to the DC out, but inverters often have some substantial smooting capacitors in them, which take a fair current when connected, so that needs to be allowed for.

Answer (score 1):

The "60A/50A/40A/30A/20A/10A" is the maximum amperage the controller can handle. You would want to size the controller based on the total amperage output of your solar panels. You have a 100  watt solar panel and if you hook it up to a 12 volt battery: 100watts / 12 volts = 8.33 amps, you would need a 10A solar controller. If you had a 1200 watt solar array and were going to use a 24 volt battery: 1200W / 24V = 50A, you would need a 50A controller.
Hope this helps..... Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want whatever battery protection the charge controller provides, feel free to attach it to the DC Load terminals of the charge controller.   **That is what it is for**.  The inverter *is* a DC load.

However *make sure* the charge controller can handle the DC ampacity the inverter can draw.

If the inverter instructions are saying to hook it up to the battery,  those may be generic instructions because they don't know your system.

Answer (score -1):

This low cost charger gives you good;

- short-circuit protection,open-circuit protection,reverse protection,over-load protection., Dual mosfet Reverse current protection ,low heat production. As long as you follow instructions on connect/disconnect sequence.

### it does not give you

- MPPT control of PV ( more cost option)
- Low V protection ( this is controlled by inverter UVLO  function.)
- matched impedance on output load ( this you choose by design and selection of load to battery ESR / inverter voltage ratio and power ratios)

Comment: Looks like @Jack glass half-empty was here